# многомерные массивы java

Tags: java

```
public class Memory3 {

    static int[][] N = new int[0][];
    int NLengh;

    void add(int[] i) {

        int[][] N22 = new int[1][];
        boolean isSorted = false;

        int[][] N3 = new int[NLengh + 1][];

        N3 = Arrays.copyOf(N, N3.length);
        N3[N3.length - 1] = i;
        NLengh++;
        N = N3;

        if (N.length != 1) {
            while (!isSorted) {
                isSorted = true;
                for (int k = 1; k < NLengh; k++) {
                    if (N[NLengh - 1 - k][0] >= N[NLengh - k][0]) {
                        isSorted = false;
                        N22[0] = N[NLengh - 1 - k];
                        N[NLengh - 1 - k] = N[NLengh - k];
                        N[NLengh - k] = N22[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Memory3 M = new Memory3();

        int[][] N22 = new int[6][];

        N22[0] = new int[]{7, 7, 3};
        N22[1] = new int[]{6, 8, 6, 4};
        N22[2] = new int[]{5, 2, 6, 5};
        N22[3] = new int[]{3, 8, 6, 7};
        N22[4] = new int[]{1, 2, 6, 2};
        N22[5] = new int[]{0, 7, 6, 4, 8};
        for (int s2 = 0; s2 < N22.length; s2++) {

            M.add(N22[s2]);

        }

        for (int r2 = 0; r2 < N.length; r2++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < N[r2].length; r++) {
                System.out.println("N[" + r2 + "][" + r + "]" + N[r2][r] + "");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Необходимо чтобы я мог в метод add передавать  массивы  различной размерности а не только  одномерные массивы int
 и уже в методе  у массива увеличивать число элементов (ссылок) на массивы.
может быть использовать обобщение?
Спасибо.

Comment: Напрямую такое не сделать. Можно объявить параметр типа `Object` тогда передавать можно все что угодно. Генерики с массивами работают плохо. Можно создать свой класс и спрятать в него логику доступа к элементам.

Comment: @talex 
1) ну почему? Сделать то можно... Но есть целый ряд вопросов, которые нужно продумывать. Да и имплементация жесткая. 

2) нужно понять, что на самом деле хотел автор. В том блоке кода, что он кинул, захардкодены  двумерные массивы. Почему речь зашла о "различной размерности" не совсем понятно

3) Вопрос больше к автору. Чем плоха реализация через коллекции? Или в задании явно прописаны массивы?

Comment: @AntonM 1) Я не представляю как тип записать. 2) Это всегда главное :)

Comment: @talex рекурсивно работаем с object-ом, на каждой новой итерации проверяя, является ли это объектом или нет (`isInstance()` в помощь). Если размерность больше или равна текущей - еще понятно что делать. А как поступать при меньшей размерности, лично для меня, большой вопрос.

Comment: @talex можно что-то вроде class `ArrayOrObject` сделать, который по get проверяет, создан ли array, иначе возвращает объект. Но опять же, с этим как-то надо работать...

Comment: @AntonM вы не поняди. Например `void f(int[]a)` принимает одномерный массив, `void f(int[][]a)` принимает двумерный массив. Как записать сигнатуру функции которая принимает произвольномерный массив? Только если `Object`.

Comment: @AntonM "можно что-то вроде `class ArrayOrObject`" в моем ответе я что-то подобное и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кастомного класса позволяющего работать с массивами произвольной (но фиксированной) размерности

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cust arr = new Cust(2, 2);

        arr.set(1, 0, 0);
        arr.get(0, 0);
    }

}

class Cust {
    private final Object arr;
    private final int dimension;

    Cust(int... dimensions) {
        if (dimensions.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rank < 1");
        }
        dimension = dimensions.length;
        arr = createArr(dimensions, 0);
    }

    private Object createArr(int[] dimensions, int index) {
        int currentRank = dimensions[index];
        if (index == dimensions.length - 1) {
            return new int[currentRank];
        }
        Object[] tmp = new Object[currentRank];
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRank; i++) {
            tmp[i] = createArr(dimensions, index + 1);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    int get(int... indexes) {

        if (indexes.length != dimension) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int[] inner = getInner(arr, indexes, 0);
        return inner[indexes[indexes.length - 1]];
    }

    void set(int value, int... indexes) {

        if (indexes.length != dimension) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int[] inner = getInner(arr, indexes, 0);
        inner[indexes[indexes.length - 1]] = value;
    }

    private int[] getInner(Object o, int[] indexes, int index) {
        if (indexes.length - 1 == index) {
            return (int[]) o;
        } else {
            Object[] tmp = (Object[]) o;

            return getInner(tmp[indexes[index]], indexes, index + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Видимо я немного не правильно обрисовал задачу.

Comment: Собственно мне это необходимо для следующего:

Comment: {
 
 int [][]  N =new int[7][];
 N[0]=new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
 N[1]=new int[] {  1, 0, 1 };
 N[2]=new int[] {  1, 1, 1 };
 N[3]=new int[] {  0, 1, 1 };
 N[4]=new int[] {  2, 0, 1 };
 N[5]=new int[] {  0, 0, 1 };
 N[6]=new int[] {  0, 0, 0 };
 }

Comment: //int [][] [] N22 = new int [0][] []
 // так будет изменяться размерность массива  и зменяться адрес размещения
 ///элементов по мере заполнения массива
 // массив int [1][1][1]   -адрес N22[0][0]    N[0]  
 
 // массив int [2][1][1]     -адрес N22[0][0][0] N[0] , -адрес N22[1][0][0]  N[1] 
 
 // массив  int [2][2][1] - адрес N22[0][0][0] N[0] , -адрес N22[1][0][0]  N[1]  
 //        адрес N22[1][0][1]  N[2] 
 
 // массив  int [2][2][2]  - адрес N22[0][0][0]  N[3] , адрес N22[0][0][1] N[1] 
 //        адрес N22[0][0][0] N[2]  , адрес N22[0][0][0] N[3] 
 
 //   и т.д

Answer (score 0):

```
{

int [][]  N =new int[7][];
N[0]=new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
N[1]=new int[] {  1, 0, 1 };
N[2]=new int[] {  1, 1, 1 };
N[3]=new int[] {  0, 1, 1 };
N[4]=new int[] {  2, 0, 1 };
N[5]=new int[] {  0, 0, 1 };
N[6]=new int[] {  0, 0, 0 };
}

int [][] [] N22 = new int [0][] []
// так будет изменяться размерность массива  и зменяться адрес размещения
///элементов по мере заполнения массива
// массив int [1][1][1]      -адрес N22[0][0]    N[0]  

// массив int [2][1][1]      -адрес N22[0][0][0] N[0] , -адрес N22[1][0][0]  N[1] 

// массив  int [2][2][1]    - адрес N22[0][0][0] N[0] , -адрес N22[1][0][0]  N[1]  
//                           адрес N22[1][0][1]  N[2]   

// массив  int [2][2][2]     - адрес N22[0][0][0]  N[3] , адрес N22[0][0][1] N[1] 
//                           адрес N22[0][0][0] N[2]    , адрес N22[0][0][0] N[3] 

//   и т.д
```

Comment: размерность заполняемого массива  предположительно до  10 вложений т.е.   int [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]  или более поэтому важно чтоб не было  ссылок на пустые массивы